# How to inject angular value and angular constant into karma unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, yeoman

I want to test this controller

**/controllers/datetimepicker.js**

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .value('smConfig', {
    rate: 'A',
    tariff: 'classic'
  })
  .controller('DatetimepickerCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'stadtmobilRates',
    'smConfig',
    function($scope, stadtmobilRates, smConfig) {
      ...
      $scope.getCurrentRate = function(rate, tariff) {
        // studi and classic have the same rates
        if (tariff === 'studi') {
          tariff = 'classic';
        }
        return stadtmobilRates[tariff][rate];
      };
      ...
    }
  ]);
```

I have changed the controller since I wrote the tests. Some constants have moved to `angular.module('c2gyoApp').value('smConfig'){}` and I also need the constant from `angular.module('c2gyoApp').constant('stadtmobilRates'){}`:

**/services/stadtmobilrates.js**

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .constant('stadtmobilRates', {
    'classic': {
      'A': {
        'night': 0,
        'hour': 1.4,
        'day': 21,
        'week': 125,
        'km000': 0.2,
        'km101': 0.18,
        'km701': 0.18
      },
      ...
});
```

This is my test so far:

**/test/spec/controllers/datetimepicker.js**

```
describe('Controller: DatetimepickerCtrl', function() {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('c2gyoApp'));

  var DatetimepickerCtrl;
  var scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    DatetimepickerCtrl = $controller('DatetimepickerCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should calculate the correct price', function() {
    expect(scope.price(10, 10, 0, 0, 'A', 'basic')
      .toFixed(2)).toEqual((18.20).toFixed(2));
      ...
  });
});
```

How do I inject `angular.module('c2gyoApp').value('smConfig'){}` and `angular.module('c2gyoApp').constant('stadtmobilRates'){}` into the test? I'm using the standard yeoman layout. The karma.conf file includes all necessary .js files, so it's just a question of where to inject the angular elements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you are adding the `c2gyoApp` module with:

```
beforeEach(module('c2gyoApp'));
```

Everything registered inside that module should be injectable.  So, this should work:

```
var smConfig, stadtmobilRates;

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _smConfig_, _stadtmobilRates_) {

   scope = $rootScope.$new();
   DatetimepickerCtrl = $controller('DatetimepickerCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
   });
   smConfig = _smConfig_;
   stadtmobilRates = _stadtmobilRates_;
}
```